# Jquery-ui doesn't work on Heroku, but on localhost yes

Tags: jquery, ruby, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-3.1, heroku

I have an app and I use there the `autocomplete` gem. It works me great on localhost. But when I deploy this app to Heroku, the `autocomplete` plugin doesn't works me. No errors in Firebug, just nothing.

Does anyone an idea, where could be a problem? 
This is how look my `Gemfile`:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.2'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'mysql2'
gem "rvm", "~> 1.9.2"
gem 'authlogic'
gem "rake", "0.8.7"
gem 'json'
gem "declarative_authorization", "~> 0.5.3"
gem "ancestry", "~> 1.2.4"
gem "taps", "~> 0.3.23"
gem "paperclip", "~> 2.4.5"
gem 'aws-s3'
gem "awesome_print", "~> 1.0.1"
gem 'actionmailer'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
gem 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.5.rc.2'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'therubyracer-heroku', '0.8.1.pre3'
  gem 'pg'
end



gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug'
```

Comment: Anything on the server log files?

Comment: I just precompiled assets and it's "working" - I am getting now the error **ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PGError: ERROR:  function lower(integer) does not exist** - but how can I to write my own search method for [this gem](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete) ?

Comment: you should create a separate question, but it depends how you're using this. It implies you're trying to search on an integer column?

Comment: @MatthewRudy I created a [new topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675393/rails3-jquery-autocomplete-and-writing-own-search-query) , because this is a new problem. I think there is needed a separate query, but I don't know where the query put it.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone coming here from Google - I searched and searched - finally - *in my case* the answer turned out the be the include directive in app/assets/application.js:

```
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
**//= require jquery_ujs**
//= require excanvas.min
//= require bootstrap.min
```

I added the ** fyi

When you take OUT that line, because you have jquery-rails gem installed (you do have jquery-rails installed right?) then run:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile:all
```

At your shell in your Rails app's root directory (I'm spelling everything out here cause a lot of times people don't explicitly state everything in their comments!)

You shouldn't get any errors - it's that :all at the end that was revealing the jquery / jquery_ujs errors.

If you just type:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

You probably won't get any errors - but jquery won't work either (this is the part that tripped me out).

When I found another comment on SO that said to add :all and it would reveal jquery erros - viola! - it told me stuff wasn't right.

So finally removing the jquery_ujs (which was documented as DON'T REMOVE THIS ON PAIN OF DEATH in other places...) and compiling and then running unicorn as though I'm in production - it works great.

The bonus of course is now that you have your assets compiled you can throw that folder up on Amazon S3, open a CloudFront account, use something like asset_sync gem - and reduce the load even more on Heroku's dynos.

BALLER

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had to delete this plugin from my gem file
gem 'sprockets_better_errors'