# rails3-jquery-autocomplete and writing own search query

Tags: ruby, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-3.1, jquery-autocomplete

This is my controller, where I use [autocomplete gem](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete). I am getting the error for this query:

```
SELECT  users.id, users.phone, first_name, last_name FROM "users"  WHERE (LOWER(users.phone) ILIKE '77%') ORDER BY users.phone ASC LIMIT 10):

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PGError: ERROR:  function lower(integer) does not exist
```

My controller:

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController
  autocomplete :user, :phone

  ...
end
```

I would like to ask you, how can I do my own db query for autocomplete searching - I need to throw it the error above and I think there is no way to do else...

I got this error, when I deployed my app to Heroku.

Comment: what type of column is `users.phone`? is it an enum or something?

Comment: well that's why it fails, its trying to do a string comparison, with an integer.

Comment: if this is a phone number, it should be stored as a string. Or else, when you store the uk number "0800123456" you'll end up returning "800123456", losing the leading 0.

Comment: I know the problem is in the use `LOWER ` function on the integer type... but I am trying to find a solution for creating my own DB query for the autocomplete gem

Comment: so you need to find a prefix of an integer? The gem doesn't seem very extensible. I'd suggest using the gem for the clientside stuff, and writing your own controller method that returns what is expected.