# Rails: jQuery-Ui does work on localhost, but not on heroku

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, heroku

My rails project works on localhost, but not on heroku.

I'm using the jQuery-ui gem. When pushed to heroku, errors like this occur:

```
TypeError: $(...).draggable is not a function
```

jQuery on the other hand works. How do I get jQuery-ui to work on heroku?

[There is a thread with the same problem, however, the proposed solutions do not work for me.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675122/jquery-ui-doesnt-work-on-heroku-but-on-localhost-yes)

`rails assets:precompile` will produce the same errors.

application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

application.css

```
 *= require jquery-ui
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end
gem 'devise'

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

code that does not work on heroku:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var callresultswal = function(){
            resultswal("Lückentext ausgefüllt!", "Du hast die Lücken korrekt ausgefüllt!", 500, "ethic", "utgf", "completed");
        };

        var points = 0;
        $( function() {
            $( ".draggable" ).draggable({ revert: 'invalid', snap: ".dropfield", snapTolerance: 75, snapMode: "inner" });

            $( ".dropfield" ).droppable({
                drop: function( event, ui ) {
                  if(ui.draggable.attr('id').toLowerCase() == $(this).attr('value')){
                      points = points + 1;
                      console.log(points);
                      var id = ui.draggable.attr('id');
                      $("#" + id).draggable( 'disable' );
                      $("#" + id).css( "background-color", "#7FFF00");
                      if (points == 6){
                          callresultswal();
                          $('#backforward').fadeIn("slow").removeClass("hidden-xl-down");
                      }
                  }
                }
            });
        } );
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Put your `javascript` code which contain `draggable`

Comment: @fool Updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the best practice is to remove `require_tree` and require each file in the following order

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require yourjsfile
```

Then you need to test your `production` environment with `rails s -e production` to see if you experience the same problem on local production environment.

A solution could be to perform `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` and then retest `rails s -e production`

If you solve the problem, remember to commit your changes to github.

If you do not solve the problem, always remember that you can inspect the heroku/local production page like this

1. go to your heroku page for ex `https://surfcheck.herokuapp.com`
2. open the chrome developer tools with `f12`
3. select the `Sources` tab
4. select the `application-fingerprinted.js` file
5. pretty pint the file with `{}`
6. search for the `jquery-ui` function `.draggable` or any other function

[image]

I had this type of `jquery-ui` problems in the past, a very simple solution was heading to the [jquery-ui](https://jqueryui.com/) site, downloading the unminified files and coping them in my `vendor` folder, deleting the gem and using those files for jquery.

Also to add, you are not getting the error in `development` because it is a precompilation issue. Your server is falling back to the files inside the gem folder as it does not find the jquery files in the `application.js`, this can be disabled in development with

```
config.assets.unknown_asset_fallback allows you to modify the behavior of the asset pipeline when an asset is not in the pipeline, if you use sprockets-rails 3.2.0 or newer. Defaults to true.
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html

Answer (score 1):

Follow the bellow order and remove the `//= require rails-ujs` line from this code

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Hope to help